# What is a "split-body" RCT?

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, clinical-trials, random-allocation, research-design

I am reading the RCT Wikipedia page, in particular the [classification by study design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_controlled_trial#By_study_design).

There are described four types of RCT: (i) parallel groups (ii) crossover (iii) cluster (iv) factorial.

Then there is written:

> An analysis of the 616 RCTs indexed in PubMed during December 2006 found that 78% were parallel-group trials, 16% were crossover, 2% were split-body, 2% were cluster, and 2% were factorial

What is a "split-body" RCT?

It is not described in the paragraph before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a trial whether the two interventions are applied to different parts of the same person.  One setting is ophthalmology, with different treatments applied to each eye, but [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02506101) is an example with different patches of skin